# How to Consistently get a User's Display Name from GitHub Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Currently, I have a Firebase Cloud Function `initUser` that is on the `functions.auth.user().onCreate` trigger.  It takes the user's display name from the auth provider (only GitHub) and creates an entry for the user in the real-time database.  I would say this works as described about one in three times.  For the other two times getting the `user` and then `displayName` from the `event` returns `undefined`.  Currently, I simply check if the user's `displayName` is `undefined` and if it is set the users name to their `uid` and if not I will set it to the `displayName` I was passed.

**Current Function:**

```
exports.initUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    //Adds the Player To Users and Scores Node
    const user = event.data;
    const uid = user.uid;
    const score = 0;
    admin.database().ref('users/' + uid).child('score').set(score);

    var name = "";
    if(user.displayName === undefined) {
        name = uid;
    } else {
        name = validator.escape(user.displayName);
    }

    admin.database().ref('users/' + uid).child('name').set(name);
    admin.database().ref('scores').child(uid).set(score);
    console.log("Created User: " + name);
    return true;
});
```

**So my question:** is this the best approach or is there a better way or known workaround to consistently get the users display name form GitHub.

*Note: I have seen people suggesting in other places to add a delay and do not accept this as an answer.*

**Edit:** The proposed answer is an improvement to the code however, it is not the root cause as the error persists.  To clarify the question is, how can I consistently avoid a user's display name from github being `undefined` specifically in the `initUser` cloud function.

Answer (score 1):

Writing data to Firebase (and most modern web APIs) happens asynchronously. When you call `admin.database()....set(...)` it only **starts** writing the data, it may take some time before the write operation is finished. But as soon as you `return true` at the end of your code, the Cloud Functions system assumes your code is done and is free to cancel any remaining operations. This race condition is the most common cause of lost writes.

To fix the race condition, you need to return a `Promise` that signals when your code it actually done. In this case you have three write operations, so you return a promise that resolves when all three are done:

```
exports.initUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    //Adds the Player To Users and Scores Node 
    var promises = [];
    const user = event.data;
    const uid = user.uid;
    const score = 0;
    promises.push(admin.database().ref('users/' + uid).child('score').set(score));

    var name = "";
    if(user.displayName === undefined) {
        name = uid;
    } else {
        name = validator.escape(user.displayName);
    }

    promises.push(admin.database().ref('users/' + uid).child('name').set(name));
    promises.push(admin.database().ref('scores').child(uid).set(score));
    console.log("Created User: " + name);
    return Promise.all(promises);
});
```

I recommend also checking out some of the other [questions dealing with `Promise.all(...)` and Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-functions%5D+Promise.all).

Comment: Thank you for the suggested improvements to my code.  However, the problem is (as I understand it) that `event.data.displayName` is undefined prior to starting the write operation

Answer (score 0):

`.onAuthStateChanged` drives the user/auth state of your app.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) { // THIS IS ASYNCH
    if (user) { //USER IS SIGNED IN NOW
        // NOW GET .displayName
    }
    else { //USER IS NOT SIGNED IN

    }
});
```

Comment: I mean specifically in the initUser function.

Comment: you'll notice `.user` is `undefined` or `null` initially after a page refresh. It "blinks" till asynch `.auth()` subsystem returns the user state. Simply rely .onAuthStateChanged and set .displayName independent of onCreate. To see it, `console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName) immediately and inside of `.onAuthStateChanged`. You'll see it blink.

Comment: I understand this and have this implemented in my client however the question is referring to firebase cloud functions specifically the initUser trigger.

Comment: Ah ..ok. got it now.